# Coreplot iOS - Remove border line around pie chart

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I've got a pie chart being generated through Coreplot. It's put a black line all the way around the chart and through all the segments like so:

[image: Coreplot example]

I generate the chart with the following code:

```
-(CPTFill *)sliceFillForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
CPTFill *areaGradientFill ;

if (index==0)
return areaGradientFill= [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.0f/255.0f green:111.0f/255.0f blue:115.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
else if (index==1)
    return areaGradientFill= [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:171.0f/255.0f green:213.0f/255.0f blue:199.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
else if (index==2)
    return areaGradientFill= [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor yellowColor]];

return areaGradientFill;
}

-(void)constructPieChart:(NSString *)datain;
{

NSArray *strings = [datain componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

dataforcharts = [datain componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"dataforcharts: %@", dataforcharts);

// Create pieChart from theme
pieGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
[pieGraph applyTheme:theme];
pieChartView.hostedGraph             = pieGraph;
pieGraph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
pieGraph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

pieGraph.paddingLeft   = 20.0;
pieGraph.paddingTop    = 20.0;
pieGraph.paddingRight  = 20.0;
pieGraph.paddingBottom = 20.0;

pieGraph.axisSet = nil;

// Prepare a radial overlay gradient for shading/gloss
CPTGradient *overlayGradient = [[CPTGradient alloc] init];
overlayGradient.gradientType = CPTGradientTypeRadial;
overlayGradient              = [overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0] atPosition:0.0];
overlayGradient              = [overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3] atPosition:0.9];
overlayGradient              = [overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7] atPosition:1.0];

// Add pie chart
piePlot                 = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
piePlot.dataSource      = self;
piePlot.pieRadius       = 100.0;
piePlot.pieInnerRadius  = 50.0;
piePlot.identifier      = @"Pie Chart 1";
piePlot.startAngle      = M_PI_4;

  //  piePlot.sliceDirection  = CPTPieDirectionCounterClockwise;
piePlot.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
piePlot.labelOffset     = -40.0;
piePlot.overlayFill     = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:overlayGradient];
[pieGraph addPlot:piePlot];

CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
textStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
textStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;

pieGraph.title=@"Chart1";

pieGraph.titleTextStyle = textStyle;
pieGraph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
pieGraph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, -1.0f);

int i = [[strings objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
int f = [[strings objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

NSLog(@"Int1: %i", i);
NSLog(@"Int2: %i", f);

// Add some initial data
NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:i], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:f], nil];
self.dataForChart = contentArray;

CPTLegend *theLegend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:pieGraph];
theLegend.numberOfColumns = 2;
theLegend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];
theLegend.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
theLegend.cornerRadius = 5.0;

pieGraph.legend = theLegend;

pieGraph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorBottom;
pieGraph.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0, -0.0);
}
```

and I'd like to remove the black lines around the chart. I've already tried setting the `borderLineStyle` to `nil` but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this and debug again, it's working.

```
piePlot.borderLineStyle = nil;
```

Comment: Indeed it does work, I just had it in the wrong place. It needs to go below where I set the overlayFill for some reason. Ah well, all working now. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to fill the inner circle(which shown in above diagram with some color? i am searching for it from hours but not able to find..if its not possible then how can we achieve that??