# Using core-plot ios sdk is it possible to draw inner circle

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

[image]

Using core plot pie chart i am able to produce this. However i want to fill the inside rect with some color is it possible?. i have used same source `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697300/coreplot-ios-remove-border-line-around-pie-chart`..

kindly suggest the other possibilities also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a second pie chart with a radius equal to the inner radius of the ring. Give it a single slice filled with the desired background color.